# Will penalty-augmented stiffness matrix cause numerical issues in eigenvalue analysis?

Tags: finite-element, eigenvalues, stiffness, penalty-method

In the finite element method, we often construct the constraints of the system by adding penalty-function terms ( which often are many many magnitudes, up to $10^6$ order bigger than the largest stiffness matrix term) to the stiffness matrix by using the [so-called Penalty Method (section 9.2)](http://www.colorado.edu/engineering/CAS/courses.d/IFEM.d/IFEM.Ch09.d/IFEM.Ch09.pdf)

[image]

**On the other hand,**

the eigenvalue analysis, as implemented by [ARPACK](http://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/), makes use of [Arnoldi iteration scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnoldi_iteration#Implicitly_restarted_Arnoldi_method_.28IRAM.29), which involves working on the stiffness matrix many times over in the iteration.

My hunch is that, the out-of-magnitude penalty term in stiffness matrix will make the whole Arnoldi iteration unstable, when it is iterated many times over, resulting in inaccuracy when we compute the eigenvalue analysis. I also don't know how to estimate the inaccuracy level .

Due to lack of competency in rigorous math, I am unable to prove my hunch. Am I right? Can anyone furnish a proof to prove or disprove my hunch?

**PS:** 
My hunch is somewhat validated by a note in the textbook reference above ( section 9.7),

[image]

But still, I'll be interested to see a rigorous mathematical argument.